# Middle point of weighted X Y

Tags: math, graph, algebra

I'm trying to get the middle point of X Y and Weight values, but I didn't found the correct formula to get that.

For example in the picture I've added a few points with a few weights and I need to found the middle point base on the weights.

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

sum (W<sub>i</sub> X<sub>i</sub>)/ sum (W<sub>i</sub>)